# SQLite '+' prefix removed in case of an integer (column type STRING)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this weird problem. I have defined a column in a SQLite database as `STRING` but when I use it with integers prefixed by a `+` it automatically converts them to a proper integer:

```
sqlite> create table test (key STRING);
sqlite> insert into test values ('+1'); 
sqlite> insert into test values ("+2");
sqlite> select * from test;
1
2
```

As you can see the `+` sign is removed. On the other hand, if I **quote** the strings **twice**:

```
sqlite> delete from test;
sqlite> insert into test values ('"+3"');
sqlite> insert into test values ("'+4'");
"+3"
'+4'
```

... it works as expected but they are quoted. My primary problem is that I need to "double quote" all strings because **I cannot guarantee that some string might look like an integer to the database and therefore be tampered with**.

This is what I would like to know:

- Why does SQLite behave like this (and maybe other implementations)?
- Can I do something about it? (Without the double quoting?)

---

Just for reference, inserting the string `'+test'` works as expected:

```
sqlite> delete from test;
sqlite> insert into test values ('+t');
sqlite> select * from test;
+t
```

*(answer without quotes - whiii!)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to SQLite's [dynamic data typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). In particular, `STRING` is not a valid type, so SQLite defaults it to `NUMERIC` affinity. In fact, to quote from that page:

> Note that a declared type of "FLOATING POINT" would give INTEGER
>   affinity, not REAL affinity, due to the "INT" at the end of "POINT".
>   And the declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not
>   TEXT.

You want to declare your column as `TEXT`, not `STRING`. That will fix it.